# JavaFX & FXML: controller event handler and initialization best practice

Tags: events, javafx, dependency-injection, event-handling, initialization

I ran into a design problem which has to do with the order of event handling and initialization of JavaFX controllers.

I want to update a TabPane, whenever the corresponding tab is selected. To achieve this, I use FXML to register the event handler as follows:

```
<Tab fx:id="browseCollectionTab" onSelectionChanged="#tabChanged" text="Browse Images">
```

In the event handling code, I got something like

```
@FXML 
private void tabChanged() throws IOException{
    if(browseCollectionTab.isSelected())
            updateImageView();
}
```

updateImageView in turn loads images using a data source passed to the controller using Dependency Injection.

**Option 1:**
This dependency injection is currently implemented as follows:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(); 

    AbstractController ctrl = (AbstractController)fxmlLoader.getController();
    ctrl.setModel(this.model);
    ctrl.setUp();
```

**Option 2**
I could use the initialize() method of the controller to initialize it using singletons. This does break the dependency injection and is not my preferred solution.

**Option 3**
I could refrain from using FXML and instantiate everything manually. This allows me to instantiate the controller and perform dependency injection before even invoking JavaFX/FXML. There are numerous examples online, which all end up in a mess for complex GUIs. I would like to stick to FXMLLoader because this seems like a neat and comfortable way. Please point it out if this is actually not the best practice.

**Option 4**
I could register the event handlers manually in the initialize() method of the controller (or for that matter, after performing the dependency injection/setting up the controller from somehwere else). This defies the point of defining event handlers in FXML in the first place.

So, what is wrong with Option 1 and 2? tabChanged is actually called before *any* initialization is performed on the controller, resulting in null pointer exceptions. Now, I could go about ignoring all events until the controller is initialized - this is probably a bad idea because events which come up just once will be missed. Another option is to enforce initialization in (probably) many event handlers. This does not seem like a viable option either.

I must be missing something obvious. I am aware that this pertains to common design choices/best practices; however, I was unable to feed the right keywords to Google.

I am looking forward to your help/suggestions - thank you!

Comment: Hi zeroByte, best example I could point out is to create the FXMLLoader before the initializer then load the fxml to the parent during the initialization process. this way the variable is accessible outside of the initialize function, but is still ready during runtime, the chosen FXML can still be adjusted by updating the FXMLLoader variable and then setting the new FXML to the parent outside of the initialize function.

Answer (score 1):

The example you show is actually a very unusual one: normally event handlers cannot be invoked before the load process is complete. Tab selection is something of an anomaly, because you are really responding to changes in properties that can happen programmatically, and indeed do happen when a tab is added to an empty tab pane. So this is an unusual case where the event handler can be invoked before loading is complete.

### Simple solution

Consider changing how you associate the controller with the FXML file. One option is to **remove the `fx:controller` attribute** from the FXML file, and set the controller in code. This gives you the opportunity to properly initialize the controller first:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
AbstractController ctrl = new ConcreteControllerImplementation();
ctrl.setModel(this.model);
ctrl.setUp();
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

---

### More complex approach

Another option, which is a little more complex, is to use a controller factory. This is a function that maps the controller class to the actual controller instance. In this case you still have the `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file (and this standard way of creating the FXML file can be considered a benefit, as it gives a tool like SceneBuilder the opportunity to check methods and `@FXML`-annotated fields exist, etc). Another benefit is that the controller factory is propagated to any FXML files included with `<fx:include>`, which allows you to initialize their controllers before they are used as well.

In the following I assume your `model` is of type `Model`:

First, define your controllers to have a constructor that takes a `Model` as a parameter, ie.

```
public class ConcreteControllerImplementation extends AbstractController {

    private final Model model ;

    public ConcreteControllerImplementation(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
        // do setup here, not in separate method...
    }

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // normal controller setup stuff here
        // any @FXML annotated fields are now initialized
    }
}
```

To create a reusable controller factory, you need a bit of reflection:

```
Model model = ... ;

Callback<Class<?>, Object> controllerFactory = type -> {
    try {
        for (Constructor<?> c : type.getConstructors()) {
            if (c.getParameterCount() == 1 && c.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(Model.class)) {
                return c.newInstance(model);
            }
        }
        // no matching constructor: just use default (no-arg) constructor:
        return type.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        // fatal...
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
};
```

Then you just do

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

This technique also allows you to use dependency injection frameworks. E.g. if you use Spring, you can just do

```
ApplicationContext context = ... ;
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(...));
loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
```

Now your controller instances will be created and managed by the Spring bean factory, and you can use Spring dependency injection to inject the model into them.